# Integrating PayPal IPN with PHP - cURL error: SSL CA cert

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm in the midst of integrating PayPal into my website.  At this stage, I am using the PayPal Sandbox along with the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator.  For the listener itself, I'm using [Micah Carrick's code](http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html). When sending an IPN through the sandbox, I received the follow error:

> cURL error: [77] Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

I originally thought the problem was that my website lacked a SSL certificate, so I purchased one and installed it.  Unfortunately, that did not solve my problem.  After doing some more research I am under the impression that I am missing a certificate file from PayPal or from cURL.  I downloaded one of the developer bundles (pp_php_soap_sdk_1) from PayPal and copied the `api_cert_chain` file into the directory of my ipn code, but that was unsuccessful.  When looking at the certificate, it appears to be expired, so perhaps that is the problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: If it's expired, that is most likely the problem. Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`. This is **not** a long-term solution.

Comment: Well that managed to get rid of the error, but I'm still not receiving the email informing me of either a valid IPN or invalid IPN.  When I type the URL of the ipn into the browser, I receive the Invalid HTTP request method error in my log, so I know my error log is working correctly.  Any idea why I would not be receiving the emails?  Secondly, given that this is not a long term solution, do you know where I obtain the proper SSL CA so I don't have to change the curl_setopt function call to false?

Answer (score 1):

Feel like an idiot, but the problem stemmed from the location I was storing the SSL CA cert.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "right" and "wrong" locations? Having a concrete example would be helpful to others that asked, like @stu.

Answer (score 1):

The file ipn_listener.php points to a file called "api_cert_chain.crt". You're most likely missing it. You can download it from: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PHP_SOAP_SDK.zip

Download and extract the zip. The file "api_cert_chain.crt" is located in the folder: PP_PHP_SOAP_SDK/php-sdk/lib/PayPal/cert. Upload the file to the directory /cert/ on your server (might need to create the folder).

I came across the solution from this website (last post): [Webmaster World](http://www.webmasterworld.com/ecommerce/4523997.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In the "ipn_listener.php" file there is code that points to the api_cert_chain.crt

```
dirname(__FILE__)."/api_cert_chain.crt");
```

You need to make sure that the path to that .crt is actually pointing to where the .crt is on your webserver.